# Is PropertiesService.getUserProperties() of Google Apps Script deprecated?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use [this S3 library](https://script.google.com/a/advanseads.com/d/1Qx-smYQLJ2B6ae7Pncbf_8QdFaNm0f-br4pbDg0DXsJ9mZJPdFcIEkw_/edit?usp=drive_web) for Google Apps Script. When I go to `testSupport.gs` and I try to run `setTestEnv`, it fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u (line 28, file "testSupport")`.

This makes sense, since I haven't set any User Properties yet, let me— oh, wait, that's not right...

[image: No User properties tab]

Even if I clone this script, I still do not have a "User properties" tab. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to set it with code. That tab is deprecated, but it means something else not UserProperties of propertiesService

Answer (score 1):

The `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` method is not deprecated.

In fact, the error message is correct. There is an important [difference between JavaScript and JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#JavaScript_and_JSON_differences).

In a JSON object property names ***MUST*** be double-quote strings.

Take a look at the following code for `testSupport.gs`:

```js
/** @define {string} */
var TEST_ENV_NAME_ = "S3LibraryTestEnv";
// todo: consider splitting into a generic testing lib?

// Format the TestEnv Object with property names in double quotes.
var S3LibraryTestEnv = '{"awsAccessKeyId":"theId","awsSecretKey":"theKey"}';

// Run test() to check it out
function test(){
  setTestEnv(S3LibraryTestEnv);
}

/**
* sets a testing Env, that's accessible from test and demo functios; and persistent for user
* 
* @param {Object} env the environment object to set for testing (should have awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey as properties)
* @return {void}
*/
function setTestEnv(env) {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

  // env is a JSON format string eg. ("Property names must be double-quoted strings")
  // No need to use JSON.stringify()
  userProperties.setProperty(TEST_ENV_NAME_, env);  
}

/**
* gets Test Env for the library, optionally skipping validing that all req constants are defined in that env
*
* @param {boolean}  
* @return {Object} key-value for the environment
*/
function getTestEnv(skipEnvValidation) {
  userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var env = JSON.parse(userProperties.getProperty(TEST_ENV_NAME_));
  // Logger.log(env);
  if (!skipEnvValidation) {
    var requiredKeys = ["awsAccessKeyId", "awsSecretKey"];

    if (env == null) {
      throw "Must set environment in UserProperties (see setTestEnvFromUI)"; 
    }
    for (var i=0; i < requiredKeys.length; i++) {
      if (typeof env[requiredKeys[i]] == 'undefined') {
        throw "Test Environment is missing required property '" + requiredKeys[i] + "'.  Define it object passed to setTestEnv().";
      }
    }
  }
  return env;
}
```

Also fixed some typo's here and there.

Comment: This is very similar to what I did just to get this script working. Does it really count as "using User Properties" if you are hardcoding the values of awsAccessKeyId and awsSecretKey in the code? Worse, those values will be retained by version control forever. The point of user properties is to use a readonly script, but I have to create a copy and make these modifications in order to use it.

Comment: @Noble use html service to create a start dialog asking for  secret keys , which can be transferred to properties

Comment: @TheMaster Ah, it's not my code, just a library that I'm using for a project. I started setting the keys in the script properties. That keeps them out of version control and I can change them whenever I need to.